# Finding a line in a text file and editing it

Tags: java, rename, file-writing

I have the following code:

```
   String mID = jTextField1.getText();
   String mType = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
   String mFName = jTextField2.getText();
   String mLName = jTextField3.getText();
   String mHomePhone = jTextField4.getText();
   String mMobilePhone = mPhone2.getText();
   String mEmail = jTextField6.getText();
   String mHomeAddress = jTextField7.getText();
   //Defines the new line of data
   String newLine = (mID + " | " + mType + " | " + mFName + " | " + mLName + " | "
   + mHomePhone + " | " + mMobilePhone + " | " + mEmail + " | " + mHomeAddress); 

    try {
        File inFile = new File("Members2.txt");
        BufferedReader br;
        FileReader reader;
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("Member2_Temp.txt", true)))) {
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
           reader = new FileReader("Members2.txt");
           String line;
           while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
               if (newLine.equals(line)) {
                   newLine = line.replace(line, newLine);
               }
               // Always write the line, whether you changed it or not.
               writer.println(newLine);
           }
            br.close();
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
       }

        File tempFile = new File("Member2_Temp.txt");
        Path source = tempFile.toPath();
        Path newdir = inFile.toPath();
        Files.move(source, newdir, REPLACE_EXISTING);

        dispose();
        new Edit_Member_Final().setVisible(true);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Edit_Member_Final.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The issue is that it prints only the edited line to the file and does not print the rest of the unedited lines.

If I have 4 records, the programs prints the edit line 4 times for some reason. How do I solve this?

Comment: I'm sure you'll find a number of good solutions from others. I just wanted to add a comment to say that when the size of the file does not present a constraint on memory, you can load the whole file into a String first, create a modified String, and then serialize that back to disk. This has the advantage that you can test your replacement method through your own code or through tests designed in JUnit, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

```
           BufferedReader br;
            try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("Member2_Temp.txt", true)))) {
               br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
               String line;

               while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
                   if (newLine.equals(line)) {
                       line = line.replace(line, newLine);
                   }

                   // Always write the line, whether you changed it or not.
                   writer.println(line);
               }
                br.close();
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
```

You are writing `newLine` only, which will have data only when it find a match

```
writer.println(newLine);
```

You should also write `line` also like this, add `else` condition

```
if (newLine.equals(line)) {
    line= line.replace(line, newLine);
}

writer.println(line);
```

Comment: Do I leave the while loop the same? or do I change it to newLine = br.readLine()?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be printing to file though. Now the records remain the same.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to print :(

Comment: @JSmithers Try now, with edit. Aslo doesn't make any sense to replace String when they are equal. ?do you want to check if the line contains that data ?

Comment: @JSmithers can you please explain, what exactly happened, I have copied the same code and is working fine

Comment: Check if `"Member2_Temp.txt` file created or not in your directory

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any change to the text file, it remains the same. Member2_Temp is not created in my directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104673/discussion-between-pragnani-kinnera-and-jsmithers).